# Can't connect to one Oracle database with ODBC

Tags: oracle, odbc, oracle12c

We are able to connect to remote Oracle server to both DBs: `10.1.1.1:1521/DB1` with user `UN1` and `10.1.1.1:1521/DB2` with user `UN2` using Oracle SQL Developer.

Using Oracle ODBC driver we are able connect only to `10.1.1.1:1521/DB1`. When testing connection to `10.1.1.1:1521/DB2` with user `DB2`, we are always getting error:

> Unable to connect
>   SQLState=S1000
>   [Oracle][ODBC][ORA]ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know
>   of service requested in connect descriptor

Any ideas what the problem could be?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: That message indicates the service you're providing to Oracle is not known by the listener. On the database server, run "lsnrctl status" or "lsnrctl status <listenerName>" to get the list of services that the listener knows about. You can supply any of the ones displayed in the output of the lsnrctl command.

Comment: http://ora-12514.ora-code.com/ (and nearby pages -- just change the hostname to your error code!) are lots of help with Oracle troubleshooting. (There's currently an issue on `ora-code`, so you may need to look to [https://web.archive.org/web/20180828082559/http://ora-12514.ora-code.com/](https://web.archive.org/web/20180828082559/http://ora-12514.ora-code.com/).)